# Div appears transparent in safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

I have been testing my site in several different browsers and noticed that in safari, a div that is supposed to slide open to display a settings menu appears as transparent. The cursor still becomes a pointer when it hovers over links in the menu and they can still be clicked, and in the inspector, it shows the menu having the proper dimensions, however it is nowhere to be seen. Any idea what could be causing this? Here is the php/html/css/jquery regarding the menu.

```
    <?php 
    if($profile_id === $_SESSION['user_id']) {
        echo '<div id="profile_settings">
                <ul class="settings_list">
                    <li class="bold"><a href="loggout.php">Sign out</a></li>
                    <li class="bold" id="edit_profile">Edit profile</li>
                    <li id="mid"><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="help.php">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="menu_line"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="profile_settings_button">
                <div id="profile_settings_click"></div>
            </div>';
    } else {

    }
?>

<style>
#profile_settings {
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #FAFAFA;
    border-top: 10px solid #FAFAFA;
    position: fixed;
    width: 0;
    top: 33px;
    right: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(210, 213, 214, 0.98);
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;

    z-index: 12;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 0px 0px rgba(250,250,250,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 0px 0px rgba(250,250,250,1);
    box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 0px 0px rgba(250,250,250,1);
}

#profile_settings_click {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-image: url(images/icons/cog.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 20px;
}
</style>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
        var countt = 0;
        var isMouse = false;
        var isOpen = false;
    if(isOpen === false) {
        $('#profile_settings_click').click(function(){
            $('.profile_pic_wrap').css("right", "145px");
            $('#profile_settings').css("width", "120px");
        });
    } else if(isOpen === true) {
        $('.profile_pic_wrap').css("right", "25px");
        $('#profile_settings').css("width", "0");
    }


        $("#profile_settings_button, #profile_settings").mouseenter(function(){
            countt++;
        });

        $("#profile_settings_button, #profile_settings").mouseleave(function(){
            countt--;
            setTimeout(function(){
                if (countt==0){
                    $('.profile_pic_wrap').css("right", "25px");
                    $('#profile_settings').css("width", "0");
                }
            },700);

        });

    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep yet to post images, but hopefully my description will suffice. Thanks!

Comment: Safari doesn't "like" width: 0;

Comment: Even when the java changes it to width: 120;?

Comment: try width: 1px; you have to specify px, %, em, etc.